# WPF: InvalidOperationException when setting hidden column in DataGrid to visible

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a user-defined data grid (inherits from `System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid`) with user-defined columns (they inherit from `System.Windows.Controls.DataGridColumn`). On the column headers (`DataGridColumnHeader` objects) there is a context menu that allows the user to hide and unhide any column in the `DataGrid` (toggles `DataGridColumn.Visibility` between `Visible` and `Collapsed`).

The problem is, that sometimes when switching the visibility back to `Visible` an `InvalidOperationException` is raised in [`BindingExpressionBase.JoinBindingGroup`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Data/BindingExpressionBase.cs,e184ab6b166fc2a2). This problem doesn't always happen but maybe in 10% of the cases. I didn't find any way to reproduce it, moreover it doesn't seem to depend on how the program is operated (speed of clicks, position of clicks and so on) because even when I use a program to simulate user inputs (AutoHotKey) the problem only happens sometimes.

What I found out up to now is, that following line in `BindingExpressionBase.JoinBindingGroup` sometimes returns `true` and sometimes `false` for the binding of the value that is displayed in column that is to be redisplayed. The error only occurs if the returned value is `false` (thus it DOES HAVE the `BindingGroup-Feature`).

```
if (!root.HasValue(Feature.BindingGroup))
```

I'm aware that it is very difficult to help me with this problem with so little information but I think it would just be too much to provide you all details right now. There are for example also user defined `Control`s in use inside the `DataGrid` columns.

Does anyone know how I could further isolate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this kind of problems when `Virtualization` is enabled and specially when `VirtualizationMode` is set to Recycling. By default virtualization is enabled in `DataGrid` and its mode is Recycling(not sure about mode though).

You can try with virtualization disabled(setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"`) and/or changing the VirtualizationMode to Standard (`VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"`).

In one of my applications I have exactly same implementation of DataGrid having similar show/Hide column implementation, with `Virtualization` disabled and I have not noticed any problem with showing/hiding the column.

Comment: Hello.

Thank you for the tip! I have a method that is used to create copies of Binding(I need this to workaround that fact that Bindings are not editable as soon as they are in use). Sometimes the BindingGroup-Property of the Binding that is to be copied is set to an empty string (don't ask me why, I don't do this explicitely in my code). However, I could solve the problem by explicitley setting the BindingGroup-Property of the copy to NULL in this situation.  

copy.BindingGroupName = binding.BindingGroupName == string.Empty ? null : binding.BindingGroupName;

Comment: I've now uploaded some code and two uml-Diagramms to the following location: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5yrwdknh20u1zbj/Code_and_UML.zip?dl=0. Please appologize that it is a bit a mess but I had to removed most parts because its a secret of our company and I must not put it on the internet. I hope it is still possible to see where the problem could lie. I'd also like to avoid discussions about the general structure of the program: Of course many things could be made much better/differently (I started with WPF about 9 month ago) but many "strange code" is due to code that I had to removed.